# jQuery animated background with many elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to create a background with many circles moving around and it really pushes the browser a bit too hard.

Is there any way I can do this without being too resource-intensive?

Here's the current code I have:
http://jsfiddle.net/2MGAE/2/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // Create all our glorious bubbles
    for (var i = 1; i <= 150; i++) {
        $('#bubbles').append('<span class="bubble' + i + '"></span>');
    }

    // Get random number
    function getRandomInt (min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    // Function to move bubbles randomly
    function moveRandom(obj) {
        var positionTop = getRandomInt(-350,1000);
        var positionLeft = getRandomInt(-700,1600);
        var positionTopNew = positionTop + getRandomInt(-50,50);
        var positionLeftNew = positionLeft + getRandomInt(-50,50);
        var size = getRandomInt(30,60);

        function animation() {
            obj.animate({
                top: positionTop + 'px',
                left: positionLeft + 'px',
                width: size,
                height: size
                }, 6000
            );
            obj.animate({
                top: positionTopNew + 'px',
                left: positionLeftNew + 'px'
                }, 6000, function() {
                    animation();
            });
        }

        animation();
    }

    // Activate bubble movement
    $('#bubbles span').each(function() {
        moveRandom($(this));
    })
});
```

Or is it just too many elements animated that it will always be a resource hog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty neat!  You may want to use the HTML 5 canvas element to do this.  It will utilize the GPU and doesn't require 3rd party js libraries.

REF:

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/07/Taking-advantage-of-GPU-acceleration-in-the-2D-canvas
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial

Comment: Yea, I'll use the canvas element.  Can't believe I didn't remember that and it was on one of my things to explore too!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things that come to mind.
You could look up how to use the `<canvas>` tag with really cool examples at Createjs.com
or
you could gopro and learn webgl and three.js which uses the gpu for cool fast 3d effects!